# How would I connect several speakers to an amplifier for multi room sound?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, speakers

I would be happy if anyone can help me with the following project I wish to build :

I have an old amplifier 4ohm impedance with A and B zones, support for mono and stereo and playing A and\or B. I would like to connect the followings to that amplifier :

- 2 speakers for stereo in room A
- 2 speakers for stereo in room B
- 1 speaker in room C (mono)
- 1 speaker in room D (mono)

I would like these speakers to allow me to :

- play an input from the amplifier and listen to it in all rooms simultaneously
- when playing simultaneously , I would like to have stereo in rooms A and B
- when simultaneously, I would like to have full sound in room C and D (mono), and not just left or right sound.

Inputs :

- Phono (turntable)
- mobile phone \ ipod
- tv

How may I accomplish it ? how can I wire the speakers and the amplifier ?
what kind of speakers would I need and would they all have to be the exact same model for this to work ?

Comment: What's the make and model of the amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

You start by having all wires run directly to where the amplifier is. If each room is going to have an impedence-matching volume control knob then you run your speakers to that knob and then from that to the amp.

Do not chain or parallel wire you speakers in wall. Even though 8 Ohm speakers might be ok in parallel for your 4 Ohm amplifier you should make that circuitry outside of the wall at the amp location.

You can't just combine left and right outputs and form mono sound. You'll need a device which can mix the stereo inputs into a mono output. If you want to do this it is likely you will need to have pre-outs on your receiver, and a second amplifier stage for rooms C and D.

My suggestion would be not to bother with mono in rooms C and D. Buy single-location speakers that have dipole coils in them so that you can run stereo sound (four conductors) to the one speaker.

In this configuration, you have four stereo requirements.

I suggest you get a switching splitter designed for this, or a power amp stage designed to power eight channels.

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! would a switching splitter provide enough current to power up 8 channels ? by saying, 8 channels you mean 8 speakers ? my old amplifier has 2 channels outputs only, how can I chain connect the switching splitter or power amp stage to this amp ?  Thanks !

Comment: @chegov Your amplifier has a max rating per channel. A splitter won't increase this power, it will just match the impedance as needed. I'd suggest that you amp with 2 channels likely doesn't have sufficient power for six speakers but I would be more certain if you gave me the model number

Comment: Hi, thanks and sorry for the delay. This is the spec and model : PHILIPS 732 (1975-1977)

2x 12 watts/2x 18 watts - 20-20.000 Hz +- 1dB at < 1% distortion - Weight 5 Kgs

Comment: currently I have 8 ohm speaker connected to it and it sounds great. I saw that it can only put up with up to 8 ohm of speakers, so I guess connecting speakers in series will be better than parallel ? thanks again