# Connecting TV to better external speakers: Type of connection

Tags: cables, speakers, television, connectors

I have a Philips 32PFL4738 81 cm [LED TV](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/3/32pfl4738_v7/32pfl4738_v7_pss_aenin.pdf) but the built-in speakers don't give great sound. I want to attach external speakers but am having a hard time figuring out what kind  would match.

The TV specs. say this:

[image]

- I've Speaker Option#1 that says: Audio input cable: Stereo Audio
  (3.5mm jack) x1
- Speaker Option#2 says: Connector Type Stereo Jack (3.5 mm)

Would any of these fit the TV?

The only output listed on the TV specs seems "CVBS". But Wikipedia says that CVBS is " analog video transmission (without audio)".

So, is there any way of getting audio out of the TV (to external speakers) at all?

**Edit (based on the excellent answer by RedGrittyBrick):**

Would a converter cable of this type work to connect the L/R RCA type audio output of the TV to the 3.5 mm Audio In port on the speakers?

[3.5mm Stereo to Dual RCA Audio Adapter Cable, 3.5mm Female to Dual RCA Male (Red/White), 6 inch](http://www.amazon.in/3-5mm-Stereo-Audio-Adapter-Female/dp/B000I23TTE)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really isn't a home improvement question. There is an electronics area where it might fit (I'm not sure); I haven't checked whether there is an A/V discussion which would be an even better fit.

Comment: @keshlam I'm confused. What's home improvement if not this? Electronics SE discourages Home Electronics questions. I see several questions very similar to this question on DIY SE. e.g. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53288/how-would-i-connect-several-speakers-to-an-amplifier-for-multi-room-sound?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/3/32pfl4738_v7/32pfl4738_v7_dfu_eng.pdf), the AV output section has L and R audio outputs that you could connect to an audio amplifier.

[image: connections diagram for TV]

[image: AVout connections]

The "Video" connector will be composite video, the L and R audio outputs will be typical [phono (AKA RCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) connectors at audio "line" levels.

[image: Phono cables]

Twin phono to twin phono cable used for stereo audio (Red is Right channel) and triple phono to triple phono cable used for composite video plus stereo audio (or for some types of component video).

If your speaker/amp has a 3.5mm stereo input you need a cable with ends like this instead:

[image]

though you can make up a lead from several combinations.

---

You will need a normal HiFi amplifier plus passive speakers or active speakers (AKA monitors in audio terminology) which are powered and include a built-in amplifier in one of the speakers - this will have phono or 1/4 jack plug or 3.5mm stereo jack inputs and a volume control.

You can't use USB loudspeakers of the sort often used with PCs.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So it seems like if I buy one of these converter cables http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41yLqPOU6bL._SX450_.jpg then I could connect it to either of the two speaker options I mentioned in my post? What do you think?

Comment: Start by choosing your speakers and see what kind of connector they need.

Comment: @bib Thanks! I shortlisted my speakers. See option #1 and option #2 in my question above.

Comment: @curious_cat: See updated answer. It depends in part on exactly what connectors come with the particular active-speakers you happen to buy. There are a huge variety of possible combinations.